# IllegalStateException displayed when changed in language

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app which has one `Activity` and two `Fragments` where second `Fragments` is a child of first. When I enter to the second `Fragments` and change the language from French to English the systems throws `IllegalStateException` when I go back to the app it says the `Fragments` already exist.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added 
SettingsFragment{d25576a #3 id=0x1020011}
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment
FragmentManager.java, line 1679
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps
BackStackRecord.java, line 781
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps
FragmentManager.java, line 2360
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether
FragmentManager.java, line 2149
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps
FragmentManager.java, line 2103
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
FragmentManager.java, line 2013
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions
FragmentController.java, line 388
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart
FragmentActivity.java, line 607
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart
AppCompatActivity.java, line 178
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart
Instrumentation.java, line 1256
android.app.Activity.performStart
Activity.java, line 6972
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

Comment: Please post the logcat error here, the `IllegalStateException` can be various. And post the part of code where the app breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the first line of your stack trace:

> IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Check your code if you add a fragment twice.

Comment: I have already debugged the code  before writing the question to find out whether I am accidentally adding the fragment twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try check `if (savedInstanceState == null)` when you add your fragment in `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_frame_layout, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before add fragment you should check that this fragment is not added yet

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, myFragment).commit();
        }
```